# What properties of a proposed new logic + inference system + set-theory must be checked to make it viable?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, model-theory, proof-theory

Suppose I would like to introduce a new trifecta of logic + inference system + set theory. What are the minimum formal properties of these systems that I must verify to demonstrate the viability of the new framework?

The one property that comes to mind is consistency: that it is not possible to deduce a contradiction in this system. Actually, I can probably get away with proving only relative consistency, under the assumption that ZFC or some other standard set theory is consistent.

Another property that comes to mind is that ZFC can be developed in the new system. However, if the the new logic + inference system are extensions of first order logic + Gentzen's natural deduction, in the sense that the new system only adds features, but doesn't detract any existing feature, from these systems, then I'm good to go, right?

Are there any other properties I *must* verify, or is consistency sufficient to merit publication in a peer-reviewed journal, or, more modestly, start using this framework in my daily work with confidence?

Comment: Is your system attempting to prove more, fewer, or the exact same theorems as some well known logic+set theory?

Comment: @DanielV: Two answers. (1) Suppose it needs to be at least as expressive as some well known logic+set theory. (2) Suppose it should be considered on its own merit, without reference to another system (for instance, would you compare modal logic to first order logic? It's apples and bananas.)

Comment: What are the goals of this new system and what can it do?

Comment: @Michael: From your question as well as from DanielV's question, I understand that there is no absolute list of properties that a proposed trifecta must demonstrate (other than consistency, I presume) in order to be considered legitimate. So suppose -- to take DanielV's lead -- that the new system can be shown to be at least as expressive as some well-known system, say First Order Logic + Gentzen's Natural Deduction + ZFC set theory. If this is the case, is consistency relative to ZFC sufficient for publication?

Comment: @Michael: And what if I cannot show relative consistency? Haven't there been systems proposed in the past that, at the time of publication, were not known to be consistent? ZF and NF come to mind. So how does it go? Can I simply publish a description of a suggested system, even if I can't show that it's consistent?

Comment: @EvanAad Your question is missing a key piece of context. You ask what makes a system "viable," and whether you can "use it with confidence" - viable for, and use for, **what purpose**? (This also impacts publishability of course - in order to publish something, you need to argue that it it somehow *significant*.) Without knowing that, this question can't be answered. I think there is likely an interesting question here, but at the moment I think there isn't enough information for it to actually be addressed. (cont'd)

Comment: That said, I think it is possible to say something about the general process of developing a logical system, and so to me this question isn't quite unclear enough to vote to close. But it's borderline - it would **really** benefit from an answer to the question above.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: The purpose is this. I was working on a problem on the border of discrete mathematics and set theory, and while proving it, some of the shortcomings of NBG became painfully clear to me. I was looking for alternative set theories. The only well-established alternative (I only explored well-established alternatives) that was able to overcome the inconveniences I was dealing with was NFU. However, I thought I could do better than NFU, so I sat down and wrote a new system, which works beautifully for me, and I would gladly take it as the foundation for all my future enterprises.

Comment: You should first clarify your motivation for wanting to devise some alternative to classical logic. And how it is to benefit the potential user. Otherwise it could just turn into a hodge podge of aimless change for change's sake.

Comment: @EvanAad So what you have is some question $Q$ which you are able to resolve in some system $S$, is that right? A priori there's nothing interesting about that; given any question I can whip up an ad hoc system which resolves it. Without further information I have no idea whether the system or solution in that system are valuable. As far as I can tell it sounds like what you've done is produce a conditional result - that *under additional hypotheses* the answer to the question is a certain thing - and the interestingness of that depends on those additional hypotheses having some sort of value.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: It's probably best if I contact an authority on set theory from my university personally and discuss my ideas with them, since I don't feel comfortable discussing my work in detail in public, since I'm seriously considering publishing my ideas.

Comment: @EvanAad People discuss their ideas in public, pre-publication, all the time. Indeed, the publication process in mathematics is so slow that most ideas are so discussed - e.g. things are posted to websites, or to arxiv, long before they show up in journals. If you're really worried about people stealing your ideas, which frankly I think is silly, you can always post something to your website or to vixra (which doesn't require an affiliation, unlike arxiv) to ensure that there's evidence of your having worked on this.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Can you publish to arxiv/vixra half-baked papers, or do they need to be publication quality? I've described my system very precisely and carefully, but I have added very little prose to explain the ideas. Can I simply publish the paper as-is, and then gradually improve upon it?

Comment: @EvanAad Arxiv is definitely supposed to be for publication-ready things. But there are truly no rules for submitting to vixra. Now as a direct consequence of that, **most of vixra is [expletive-deleted]** and almost nobody serious reads it, but if what you're worried about is someone stealing your ideas - which, again, I *really* don't think is an issue - what you're getting out of it is evidence of your work that you can use in the future if necessary. As such, all that matters is that it exists.

Comment: @EvanAad *"would you compare modal logic to first order logic? It's apples and bananas"* In fact, they're quite closely related: Modal Logic is a fragment of FOL, to be precise, it is the fragment of FOL that is closed under bisimulation, which is Van Benthem's Theorem. *"Can I simply publish a description of a suggested system, even if I can't show that it's consistent?"* Note that we don't know if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent either, or for that matter any system stronger than $\mathsf{PA}$ since it's impossible to prove that.

Comment: @EvanAad *"some of the shortcomings of NBG became painfully clear to me."* I would be interested to hear some of those shortcomings. That's also perhaps a good step towards determining whether your system is relevant: what do you think is wrong about the old system.

Comment: @Vsotvep: There's nothing new in my criticisms of NBG that has not been observed in the past. They fall into two categories: (1) The weakness of the system. This has been observed by such people as Russel, Quine and Groethendieck each of whom devised an alternative system to overcome these faults. (2) The lack of non-atomic terms. Formal attempts to rectify this go back to Hilbert and Bourbaki with their eplison and tau notations, to modern day computerized proof assistants. My system addresses the same shortcomings in a different way.

Comment: @Vsotvep: With regards to point (2) I forgot to mention Church's lambda calculus where you'll find nothing but terms.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: If I publish on Arxiv, can the same paper be republished later in a respectable journal, or will the paper be considered "burned" once it's already been published?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, it can in principle be published later.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: And what if, instead of (or in addition to) publishing on Arxiv, I present the paper at a conference. Can the paper later be published in a journal?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, unless the conference has a proceedings in which that paper appears, but that constitutes a publication as well. **There are no publication-related dangers around posting on arxiv** (or vixra or your personal website), and any journal which claims that there are is not reputable). Rather than keep discussing this in the comments, I think it would be more appropriate to ask further questions in a separate question, either here or at academia.stackexchange (I think the latter would be a bit more appropriate). That said, **none of this should be taken as a guarantee of acceptance**.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds from the comments like what you've done is the following: you've taken some existing mathematical problem, and found a framework in which it can be resolved. Now you're looking for a checklist of criteria you can use to argue for that system. I don't really think that such a checklist exists; each system has to be argued for on its own terms, and while it's possible to delineate a couple key points, those points are so subjective that the checklist picture is really misleading.

From the perspective of mere coherence, what you've described is a perfectly reasonable thing to do: results of the form "In such-and-such a framework, here's an argument showing such-and-such a fact" are perfectly meaningful. Certainly there's nothing stopping you from producing lots of such results. However, that leaves open the possibility that your system is trivial *(= proves everything; in paraconsistent logic, this is different from mere inconsistency)*. It also doesn't make those results inherently interesting. Merely resolving a question doesn't justify a system - you need to somehow argue that you got the right answer, or at least a valuable perspective, and that in turn relies on a *preceding* justification of the system itself. While per my above statement I don't think there's a general template for this, there are a couple key points to hit:

- It needs to be at least plausibly nontrivial. A proof of consistency relative to some reasonably-accepted system is great; at the very least you need some explanation of why the usual paradoxes don't go through.
- Each addition to or removal from some pre-existing reasonable system needs to have some interest or justification. If the former, you're claiming that the system you're looking at is worth understanding, regardless of whether it's worth adopting; if the latter, your justification needs to be "non-explosive" - it better not be the case that I can take it and run with it to justify all sorts of nonsense.

All of this is subjective (e.g. what does "reasonably-accepted" mean above?), **and so is community response**. There's no way to tell how something is going to be received without showing it; nor is there a guarantee that what the community thinks one day will be what it thinks the next day. One important thing here is to ask yourself honestly the **"So what?"** question: seriously take the position of someone who is extremely skeptical, and try to articulate as best as possible your responses to all the objections you can think of.

Comment: [I've written another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297809/a-first-order-logic-extended-with-binding-terms-like-the-familiar-set-descriptor) related to my motivation for the present question. Would you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

First, the easiest case: if you are creating a logic+axioma that induces the same theory as some well researched well known logic.  For example, creating a new first order set theory with the same grammar and symbols and intended meaning to the symbols as normal natural deduction + zfc (lets call that Common).

In this case, all you have to do is prove 2 things, first (1) soundness.  This can be done by proving that every theorem in your logic is provable in Common.  This can usually be done by proving that all your axioms and inferences are provable in Common.

Then you can establish (2) completeness.  This can be done by the converse, by proving that every theorem in Common is a theorem in your logic.  This can usually be done, similar to above, by proving that every inference and axiom of common is a theorem of your logic.

---

An alternative approach is to establish a model theory semantics for your logic, and attempt to prove the correctness of your logic relative to that.  If this approach interests you then you should look up some first order logic proofs of soundness and completeness to get an idea what it is about.  If your logic is similar enough to another logic for which the model theoretic soundness and completeness have been established, then this is a lot of unnecessary work.  If your logic uses a very unusual language, then this might be necessary.

---

If you are creating a weaker logic+axioma, then to establish completeness you can reduce it to only theorems in Common minus those missing from yours that need to be established.  If you are attempting to create a stronger logic+axioma, that's when soundness makes things get a bit tricky.  I would suggest the following as a goal in that case:

> Prove for every statement in your language which is both provable and computable, that it computes correctly.

So for example, your logic should never produce $a \not \in \{a, b\}$.  If you are producing a logic about arithmetic then the computable statements are the $\Delta_0$ statements in the [Arithmetic Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).  If you are producing a logic about sets then the computable statements are the $\Delta_0$ statements in the [Lévy Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy) (I am not at all familiar with the Lévy hierarchy, someone please comment or correct me if I am wrong about that.)  If you are creating some kind of bizarre modal logic, then you have to determine which operators, when given computed inputs, which of them can immediately compute an output.  At least the set of theorems made of those operators must be correct.

This is a very challenging thing to attempt, and I'm not even sure how you would begin to attempt such a thing.  But if you really do want to create a bizarre logic that is vastly different than the norm, this is where I would recommend starting.

> Suppose it should be considered on its own merit, without reference to another system

I'm not sure that even makes sense.  You always have to compare it to something, even if it just human intuition.  The real question is what is the best thing to compare it to.

> Are there any other properties I must verify, or is consistency sufficient to merit publication in a peer-reviewed journal, or, more modestly, start using this framework in my daily work with confidence?

Well those are 2 very different questions.  For the first, there are journals that will publish almost *anything*.  And I think any high standards journal is not going to care about "hey I came up with a new logic isn't that neat" because people can just about algorithmically invent new logics.  You'd need to establish something important and insightful about your new logic.  Or show how it is useful to solve a problem.  The days of just showing the profoundness of reducing mathematics to logic ended 100 years ago.

And as far as using a logic for your own personal use, just try to avoid [NIH syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

Comment: What does it mean to say that a statement in a logical system is "computable"?

Comment: It really depends, but basically a statement that can be immediately evaluated.  I gave 2 examples of sets that could be considered computable, the two $\Delta_0$ sets.  It means a statement that is (maybe by some predetermined translation) exactly a program in some computational model.  So "there is an infinite number of primes" would not be a computable statement for most computational models, but "11 is prime" would be.

Comment: Once you tie the computational model to the structure in question, you get consequences for your logic that I don't think you want. For example, in the language of set theory there are no $\Delta_0$ sentences without parameters since there are no closed terms, and adding even tame parameters makes things go crazy from our perspective (e.g. if we have $\omega$ as a parameter, then the consistency of ZFC itself is $\Delta_0$!). That's not to say that this kind of "structure-specific" analysis isn't interesting, certainly I look at such things, but I don't think it's being treated correctly here.

Comment: I might be able to understand what you say better if you could say it in terms of arithmetical logic.  (Doing my best to understand you) for sets, I guess it depends on what you mean by "the language of set theory".  In literal ZFC the language is just predicate logic with $\in$.  In colloquial practice, the statement $\{a, c\} \subseteq \{a, b\} \cup \{c, d, e\}$ would be considered a statement in the language of set theory.  I could see how using literal set theory would make figuring out a set of computable statements difficult (or even pointless).

Comment: What is "arithmetical logic"? Do you just mean first-order arithmetic? In that case things are nicer, since every $\Delta_0$ formula is extremely easy to check - and actually the $\Delta_0$ predicates are a proper subset of the primitive recursive ones, which in turn are a proper subset of the $\Delta_1$ ones which correspond to computability. If you're using an enriched language for set theory, though, you should specify what it is (especially since set-builder notation is actually a bit tricky in this context). My point is just that the notion of "computable sentence" here is quite slippery.

Comment: [I've written another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297809/a-first-order-logic-extended-with-binding-terms-like-the-familiar-set-descriptor) related to my motivation for the present question. Would you please have a look at it?