# Proofs that monadic second order logic is not compact

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

I was reading [this comment by Simone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297809/a-first-order-logic-extended-with-binding-terms-like-the-familiar-set-descriptor#comment6784260_3297833) on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3297833) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297809).

The comment is reproduced below, emphasis mine.

> Well, It's not an extension that uses the notation you use, but all axioms remain and all theorems of FOL remain true. **Plural logic loses compactness.**

I find this interesting because I intuitively think of plural logic as a well-behaved cousin of FOL, but don't know how to square this intuition with [Lindström's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem).

Plural logic is very similar to monadic second-order logic, so I'd like to restrict attention to monadic second-order logic. I'd also like to restrict attention to the full semantics since I strongly suspect that, with the Henkin semantics, monadic second order logic is a paraphrase of multi-sorted FOL and is thus sompact already.

I'm curious if there's a simple go-to example of an infinite family of sentences in monadic second-order logic that's finitely satisfiable but not satisfiable.

I'm also curious more generally if there's an alternative method of proving non-compactness that doesn't require us to cook up an example (or appeal to Lindström's theorem, which seems excessively powerful for such an application).

---

Here's my attempt to prove the theorem myself. I'm not sure that the $\varphi$ in my construction below *really* succeeds in ruling out *every* nonstandard model of arithmetic. It's also possible that there's a *much* easier way to prove this that I'm not seeing (assuming that it's even true).

Consider the language of Peano arithmetic plus a new constant symbol $c$.

Let $\Phi$ be the first-order axioms of Peano Arithmetic; $\Phi$ is infinite.

Let $W$ be $\{ c > 0, c > 1, c > 2, c > 3 \cdots \}$. I'm going to use $W$ to give me a nonstandard integer.

Let $\varphi$ be the proposition promising me a unique inductive set containing $0$.

$$ \varphi \;\; \text{is} \;\; \exists! U \mathop. 0 \in U \land (\forall x\mathop. x \in U \to x + 1 \in U) $$

I claim that the standard model of Peano Arithmetic with a suitably large standard integer chosen as the value for $c$ is a model of all finite subsets of $\Phi \cup W \cup \{\varphi\}$.

I claim that $\varphi$ insists that the model of any $\Delta \ni \varphi$ is standard.

I further claim that any model of PA in which $W \cup \Phi$ holds is nonstandard.

Therefore $\Phi \cup W \cup \{ \varphi \}$ is unsatisfiable.

Therefore compactness fails for monadic second-order logic.

Comment: Your example works. Incidentally, note that over the theory $$\{\forall x,y,z,w(f(x,y)=f(z,w)\iff x=z\wedge y=w)\}$$ (with $f$ a binary function symbol) monadic second-order logic is as strong as full second-order logic, because we can use $f$ to "encode" an arbitrary-arity relation as a unary relation.